# How to add maven dependencies to Scala project

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I'm doing a research project and i need to use [this project written in Scala](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) .

With eclipse i have created a scala project in which i put the **HELLO CAPS** code.

however the project needs maven dependencies to be set :

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.opencypher</groupId>
 <artifactId>spark-cypher</artifactId>
 <version>0.1.5</version>
```

My question is how to set this maven dependencies in this Scala project ?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the question. After cloning the repo. Import it as a maven project. If you have additional dependencies to add then add the above dependency to the `pom.xml` under the `<dependencies>` tag. Then do a maven update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) create a project-folder with `pom.xml` in it.**

Example;

```
mkdir my-project
cd my-project
touch pom.xml
```

**2) Then add dependencies to `pom.xml`**

Example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.group-name</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.6</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opencypher</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-cypher</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**3) That should be it. Then you can run `mvn clean compile` from root of your project, which will download dependencies for you.**

Example:

```
mvn clean compile
```

You can see the downloaded dependencies in local maven repo;

```
$ ls -l ~/.m2/repository/org/opencypher/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 ast-9.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 expressions-9.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 front-end-9.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 front-end-parent
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi-api
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi-ir
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi-logical
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi-relational
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 okapi-trees
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 parser-9.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 rewriting-9.1
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 spark-cypher
drwxr-xr-x  3 prayagupd  184630988  102 Jul 15 12:53 util-9.1
```

**4) Now you can import your project using eclipse or intellij. (You can skip step 3 as IDEs can do `mvn clean compile` for you as well)**

**Also read:** 
[create a new maven hello-world project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29147687/432903)

Comment: Thank you, this resolve the maven dependencies but **i can't add a scala class** in this maven project ?

Comment: You can. Add `src/main/scala` folder by yourself. That is where you keep scala files. Do `mkdir -p my-project/src/main/scala` or else your IDE can create folders as well.

Comment: yes but i still can't run it as Scala Application Since it isn't  a scala project

Comment: Ok can you right click on your main function and run as scala application, if not you might need to add scala plugin in eclipse or add the scala jar to library path. This link might help you - [configure run in eclipse for Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048321/432903)

Comment: there is no main function you can see the **Hello Caps** code [here](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark)

Comment: i can the program from folder without elipse with this cmd :
    
     **>mvn scala:run -DmainClass=org.opencypher.example.HelloCypher**

Comment: Actually what is missing is  **scala plugin** for eclipse and [Maven Integration for Scala IDE](http://alchim31.free.fr/m2e-scala/update-site/)